# What is the proper way to say "beating egg whites"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

I want to say "beating egg whites" ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jxwf1sRiVaM) for reference). How do you say that in Japanese ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term for whisking egg whites is [卵白]{らんぱく}を[泡]{あわ}[立]{だ}てる.